# Generic functions vs extension methods

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I'm a C++ developer who tries to play with C# generics.
My final goal is to mimic template specialization in C#.

In other term, I want a default implementation of a function available for all types and a specific implementation for a specific type.

My first attempt was with generics and extension methods but it seems C# generics are resolved at run-time, which gives this weird result (weird for a C++ programmer at least):

```
//any of my classes
public class MyClass
{
}

//class extension for my classes only
public static class MyClassExt
{
    public static string GetCaption(this MyClass c)
    {
        return "MyClass caption";
    }
}

//"default" extension for all
public static class objectExt
{
    public static string GetCaption(this object o)
    {
        return $"object caption {o}";
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    public static string GetCaption<T>(T t)
    {
        //Isn't it supposed to call MyClassExt.GetCaption if t is MyClass ?
        return t.GetCaption();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(i.GetCaption());              //> object caption 0
        Console.WriteLine(new MyClass().GetCaption());  //> MyClass caption

        //calls GetCaption<T> with T is MyClass
        Console.WriteLine(GetCaption(new MyClass()));   //> object caption csharpconsole.MyClass
    }
}
```

What is the usual way to handle such case in C#?

Edit:

trying to implement @Enigmativity suggestion, I've tried this with no success:

```
//class extension for my classes only
public static class MyClassExt
{
    //My attempt for @Enigmativity suggestion
    public static string GetCaption<T>(this T t) where T : MyClass
    {
        return "MyClass caption";
    }
}

//"default" extension for all
public static class objectExt
{
    public static string GetCaption(this object o)
    {
        return $"object caption {o}";
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    public static string GetCaption<T>(T t)
    {
        //Isn't it supposed to call MyClassExt.GetCaption if t is MyClass ?
        return t.GetCaption();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(i.GetCaption());              //> object caption 0
        Console.WriteLine(new MyClass().GetCaption());  //> MyClass caption
        
        //calls GetCaption<T> with T is MyClass
        Console.WriteLine(GetCaption(new MyClass()));   //> object caption csharpconsole.MyClass
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you actually need extension methods? Why does `MyClass` not just have a `GetCaption` method instead, and maybe it should be an interface?

Comment: @Charlieface I missed clarification, indeed. I don't want GetCaption being part of MyClass because it's part of another "layer". Let say GetCaption is for UI only though MyClass is decoupled from UI

Comment: @LoicJourdan - Your edit does ***not*** implement my suggestion. See my answer for the full code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My final goal is to mimic template specialization in c#.

I think that's unlikely to end well, to be honest. Generics *aren't* like C++ templates; they're used to accomplish similar goals, but with quite different approaches.

> My first attempt was with generics and extension methods but it seems c# generics are resolved at run-time

No, that's not true - which explains the result you're getting.

When compiling the code for `GetCaption<T>`, the compiler resolves the call to `t.GetCaption()` without knowing anything about `T`, so the only extension method it *can* call is the one with the first parameter of type `object` - which is what you're seeing.

Basically, you need to remember that each generic method is only compiled *once* - not once against each type argument. Everything flows from that understanding: you can see polymorphism in terms of overriding, as normal, but not *overloading* where a different method is chosen at compile-time.

Comment: If I rephrase, c# generics are still generics once compiled? is it what you mean when you say "without knowing anything about T" ?

Comment: Yes: the IL for `GetCaption<T>` still "knows" that it's generic, and there's a single piece of IL for it. When compiling `GetCaption<T>`, the compiler doesn't know anything about what `T` will be because the use of `GetCaption<T>` may be in code that hasn't even been written yet.

Answer (score 2):

If you change the extension method to this:

```
public static string GetCaption<T>(T t) where T : MyClass
```

Then it will call the `MyClass` extension method as the compiler can tell that this is the most specific method to call.

Without the `where T : MyClass` then the `object` extension method is the most specific ***that it can determine at compile-time***.

When I run your code with  `where T : MyClass` I get:

```
object caption 0
MyClass caption
MyClass caption
```

Without it, exactly as you posted it, I get:

```
object caption 0
MyClass caption
object caption MyClass
```

---

Here is the full working program.

```
//any of my classes
public class MyClass
{
}

//class extension for my classes only
public static class MyClassExt
{
    public static string GetCaption(this MyClass c)
    {
        return "MyClass caption";
    }
}

//"default" extension for all
public static class objectExt
{
    public static string GetCaption(this object o)
    {
        return $"object caption {o}";
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    public static string GetCaption<T>(T t) where T : MyClass
    {
        //Isn't it supposed to call MyClassExt.GetCaption if t is MyClass ?
        return t.GetCaption();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(i.GetCaption());              //> object caption 0
        Console.WriteLine(new MyClass().GetCaption());  //> MyClass caption

        //calls GetCaption<T> with T is MyClass
        Console.WriteLine(GetCaption(new MyClass()));   //> object caption csharpconsole.MyClass
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Enigmativity, 
I've tried this already but I'm getting the exact same behavior.

Comment: @LoicJourdan - Please post your exact code. Before posting my answer I checked it worked.

Comment: @LoicJourdan - I've added my output to the answer.

Comment: Hi @Enigmativity, I've edited the question to add my attempt, thanks again.

Comment: Hi @Enigmativity, Thanks and sorry for such late answer, I've been away for quite a while.
What you are doing in the code you posted removes entirely the need of generic GetCaption<> since it's now restricted to MyClass.
The goal is to get a unique GetCaption that works with all types and can have different implementation depending on the type (as we have in c++ template specialization)
Anyways, thanks again, I appreciate